# Conditional Statement in Wix installers

Tags: wix

I am struggling to get to work a set of conditional statements using the condition tag in Wix. In my wix file I need to check the value of the property tag, and the value meets to either four values to execute the source path in either one of the corresponding file tags.

Now I created four component tags with ids and guids and four condition tags using the CData component with property tag equalling either one of the four values I am looking for.

When I compile the wix, it says that are duplicate components along with some guid like number. This strange as I have very cautiously set unique ids to each tag.

So, can someone please advise how I can use a value from a property tag, and check the value against a condition?

```
 <property id="myproperty" value="somevalue"/>

    <component id="someComponent" Guid="someGuid">
      <condition><![CDATA[myproperty="somevalue"]]></condition>
        <file id="myfile" source="C:\somevalue\bat.exe"/>
    </component>

    <component id="someOtherComponent" Guid="someGuid">
        <condition><![CDATA[myproperty="someothervalue"]]></condition>
           <file id="myotherfile" source="C:\someothervalue\bat.exe"/>
    </component>
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question,

Comment: Try to set different GUID for each component and set property ID all capital letters. also add a keypath for each file. please let me know if it worked.

Comment: Solved the problem. Didn't need to do what you suggested. The problem was due to do with linked files. Doing a copy rather than a link solved it